# How to replace words using dictionary based on sentences

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
string1 = "Hello World"
string2 = "Welcome to the World"
string3 = "The Hello World is a python statement"

dictionary = {"Hello World": 1, "World": 2, "The Hello World is a python statement":3}
```

Expected Output:

```
string3 = "3"
```

I am doing a project where I am using dictionary to replace words but the output I get is

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
  string3 = string3.replace(key, value)
print(string3)
```

Output from the code

```
 string3 = "The 1 is a python statement"
```

This is a sample example but I am working on a more broaded project. Can someone kindly make me understand why would this happen.

Comment: What version of python are you using? It looks like the `dictionary` was not ordered, thus `World` got replaced first, then the resulting `The Hello 2 is a python statement` no longer has `Hello World` to be replaced.

Comment: Your code works fine for me(python 3.10)

Comment: You'll need to do `string3 = string3.replace(key, str(value))` or you'll get a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

Regular dict objects store the values by hashing the key and using that for lookups, which doesn't keep the order, but makes lookup faster.
If you want to replace in specific order , you can use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

```
string1 = "Hello World"
string2 = "Welcome to the World"
string3 = "The Hello World is a python statement"

dictionary = {"Hello World": "1", "World": "2" ,"The Hello World is a python statement":"3"}

for key in sorted(dictionary.keys(),reverse=True,key=len):
  string3 = string3.replace(key, dictionary[key])
print(string3)
```

This will sort all the keys in increasing length .

You can also create a custom comparator to sort keys. [This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-does-the-functools-cmp_to_key-function-works-in-python/) will help.

Comment: Worth noting that as of python 3.7 dictionaries are ordered. See docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict (search for "Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order.")

Comment: In dictionaries can't we do something which replaces the words only when the whole sentence is present in the dictionary

Comment: @Akshat Jaitly even if we order the dictionary this could happen with some other words. The dictionary key should exactly match the whole sentence to replace the value

Comment: @sha25 I have updated code. Sorting keys by length would do the trick.